# NPE in my service class of rest using jersey with spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jdbctemplate

I am new to spring and rest i am still learning it. I have a problem while calling the resource from my rest api through a client.

I have some data in my database and i am using spring to inject the values and get connection.

When i am making a GET request from the client i am getting a NPE.

Below is my DAO Class

```
public interface CustomerDao {

public List<Customer> getCustomersDao();

}
```

DAOImpl

```
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

private JdbcTemplate template;

@Autowired
public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public List<Customer> getCustomersDao() {
    return template.query("SELECT * FROM books.customers", new RowMapper<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {
            Customer e = new Customer();
            e.setId(rs.getString(1));
            e.setName(rs.getString(2));
            e.setAge(rs.getString(3));
            return e;
        }
    });
}
```

Service class

```
public class CustomerService {

@Autowired
CustomerDao customersConnection;

public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {

    return new ArrayList<Customer>(customersConnection.getCustomersDao());

}
```

Resource

```
@Path("/persons")
public class CustomerResource {

@Autowired
CustomerService customerService;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Customer> getAllCustomers {

    return customerService.getAllCustomers();

}
```

}

My bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sumanth.customers" />

<bean id="ds"   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="--:--://----/---" />
    <property name="username" value="----" />
    <property name="password" value="-----" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerService" class="com.sumanth.customer.db.CustomerDaoImpl">
    <property name="template" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<servlet>

    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sumanth.customer</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sumanth.customer.resource.CustomerResource.getAllCustomers(CustomerResource.java:23) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Error line 23 :

```
return customerService.getAllCustomers();
```

I used the @Autowired to wire the beans.I know that i did a mistake while wiring them can anybody please help me out

Thank you

Comment: is it on getBooks or getAllCustomers ?

Comment: edited it is getAllCustomers

Comment: i think you are using jersey+spring.Use @InjectParam instead of Autowire and check

Comment: I believe your issue is the spring jersey bridge. There is a dependency to add which will link spring DI and jersey DI together. Read more about it here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html

Comment: @Vaibs I am using jersey 2 I didn't find that annotation.any idea?

Comment: @pandaadb WHen I add the jar jerset-spring3 to my class path I get an error " Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications to the web xml and my bean.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/bean.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Modified my service class

```
   @Component annotation in my service class
```

My bean.xml added the below

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

My Impl class.I have added the annotation above my class

```
@Repository("customerService")
```